# How to get the Bode Plot of both magnitude and phase?

Tags: frequency, bode-plot

I want to know if there is any instrument which gives the Bode plot of both magnitude and phase simultaneously? For instance, a CRO displays the waveform as soon as we connect its probes to a given circuit. Is there anything same for the Bode plot?

Answer (score 1):

That would be a Network Analyzer.

[Here's an example of one.](http://www.newtons4th.com/products/frequency-response-analyzers)

[Some scopes can do that too.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDSJmPHhIJQ)

You need to be aware it's a transfer function measurement you're making. So you need input (source) probes and output (measurement) probes.

Comment: Actually my teacher gave this as a project and told us that it hasn't been done yet by anyone. I didn't really understand what she meant by that..

Comment: Citing from Wikipedia "A Bode plot /ˈboʊdi/ is a graph of the transfer function of a linear, time-invariant system versus frequency, plotted with a log-frequency axis, to show the system's frequency response. It is usually a combination of a Bode magnitude plot, expressing the magnitude of the frequency response gain, and a Bode phase plot, expressing the frequency response phase shift." . So it seems odd to say it hasn't been done by anyone. In fact measurements like that are very common.